# AWS Lambda with API proxy

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am totally confused with the multiple options that arise but I would prefer to check whether this is doable via AWS Lambda.More specifically,I would like to be able to forward a request from an AWS API GW to a Lambda function, do some  calculation/db queries via Lambda and based on the output of the calculation,reply with error or forward the request to a backend system (HTTP REST API).Has anyone prior experience with this?Does Lambda offer such a functionality?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do so via Lambda. Based on the calculation, you can either do a callback that will return response through first API or you can call the second (HTTP) API using any HTTP library depending on the runtime you use for Lambda. Basically what you are asking is not related to the functionality Lambda offers - if it can be done via code on a local machine, it should be possible to do via Lambda as well.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I know that it can be done via any language but there is a requirement that it should be implemented via Lambda. Pardon me if I did not get it right from your first reply but my concern is whether I can do custom db lookups/data calulations before doing any API callback or second API calls.The conceptual scheme is sth like: API GW <-->Lambda db lookup/data comparison <-->Callbacks/secondary calls

Comment: You should be able to do db lookups/data calculations in Lambda. If you know what DB you are going to be using, might be a good idea to check what available libraries you have for it.